# Produce swagger configuration using java

Tags: java, swagger

I would like to know if it's possible and how to produce swagger configuration and documentation by using java.

Comment: Sure, plenty of options. Look at [swagger-parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) and [swagger-core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) as examples of such libraries.

Comment: I've already been in there, could you please be more specific?

Comment: I think it would be better if you could expand your question to explain what exactly it is you're looking for. As it stands, it is very broad, and you're unlikely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: I am quite new in REST services and swagger documentation. I would like to know if it's possible to build a swagger documentation using Java.